# Structure you walk under or through while entering a settlement

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm asking for the specific type of structure that you would see when entering a settlement. They are usually over the road and you have to drive under them.

[image: Image of gateway]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first word that occurred to me was [archway](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/archway):

> an entrance or passage formed by an arch

Answer (score 2):

It’s a gate to the city.

Photos of many such gates can be seen on Google Images. Search for “gate to the city.”

See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_gate, which notes that:

> City gates were traditionally built to provide a point of controlled access to and departure from a walled city for people, vehicles, goods and animals. . . City gates, in one form or another, can be found across the world in cities dating back to ancient times to around the 19th century.

Comment: Gates traditionally provide a way to block access as well as allowing it.

Comment: And the old city gates did exactly that, often being guarded, closed at night, and the like. What do you think “controlled access” means?

Comment: I don't see controlled access mentioned in the Q. I don't see a gate in the Q.

Comment: Did you look at the sources, and the huge number of photos labelled “gate to the city” or “city gate?”